# How to remove everything MATE related?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, mate

I recently installed MATE desktop on ubuntu 16.04 and later decided to uninstall it. I did so using the command`sudo apt-get remove mate-desktop`.

It was uninstalled and was no longer available on the login screen as an option. But i think that not everything related to MATE was removed. I know this because i still have MATE-terminal in my applications list. I could, of course, just uninstall it but then what about other hidden items that are not so obvious. I prefer not having them at all.

I tried running the commands suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180301/how-to-remove-mate-desktop-from-ubuntu-12-04.), but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try `sudo apt autoremove --purge mate-desktop && sudo aptitude purge ~c`

Comment: @user4901968 I ran this command and it removed 23 items amounting to ~37MB.  Still, the MATE-Terminal remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this list and remove everything you don't want: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-mate-desktop

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Initially i tried removing each package i had comparing it with the list from the page. Later i used the short command to remove MATE from http://askubuntu.com/questions/147858/how-to-remove-desktop-environments. This solved all my problems.