# apt-get remove with wildcard removed way more than expected. why?

Tags: apt, package-management, regex

Last night I was trying to burn CDs. Being annoyed with k3b and choosing to use brasero instead, I went to remove k3b.

I typed in:

```
sudo apt-get remove k3b
```

I hit tab twice and saw that I had both k3b and k3b-data on my system. Assuming that I wouldn't need k3b-data on my system without k3b, I wanted to remove it as well so I typed in:

```
sudo apt-get remove k3b*
```

Unfortunately I hit Y to confirm without looking. It uninstalled a whole lot more than `k3b` and `k3b-data`. It uninstalled packages which did not fit my `k3b*` regex. For example: `transmission` and `network-manager`.

I'm fairly certain that I didn't have a space between `k3b` and `*` but I don't know why else it would remove all that it did. Is there something about apt-get that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Related: [How to fix Ubuntu after accidentally uninstalling many packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/how-to-fix-ubuntu-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages)

Answer (score 70):

The command you want is `sudo apt-get remove '^k3b.*'`, because:

- You need `.*` to match any character, any number of times
- You need `^` to match the start of the string
- You need to quote the regex to prevent bash from interpreting `*` as a wildcard

(This answer completes and summarizes previous info provided by qbi and Flimm)

Comment: This is safe and it's okay to use it but you don't need the `.*`. You can just use `sudo apt-get remove ^k3b`. The presence of `^` is sufficient to cause the argument to be interpreted as a regular expression, and when `apt` or `apt-get` interprets an argument as a regular expression, it matches it *anywhere* in the package name. That's why you need `^`--to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the match to the start of the package name. The regular expression doesn't need to match the entire package name, just any part of it.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thx for the additional info! (and indeed, it makes sense that if you need `^`, then you don't need `.*`)

Comment: note that this works for apt-get not apt.

Comment: @VincentGerris it works in my apt, in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 39):

The regular expression `*` stands for zero or arbitrarily many. So you told `apt-get` to remove anything which contains  `k3` followed by any number of `b`, so basically everything which contains `k3`. If I try your command on my system it wants to remove 58 packages.

```
sudo apt-get remove -s k3b*
Package k3b is not installed, so not removed
Package k3b-data is not installed, so not removed
Package k3b-dbg is not installed, so not removed
Package libcanberra-gtk3-0 is not installed, so not removed
Package libcanberra-gtk3-0-dbg is not installed, so not removed
Package libcanberra-gtk3-dev is not installed, so not removed
…
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  appmenu-gtk ardour audacity brasero brasero-cdrkit firefox-globalmenu
  gconf-editor gir1.2-appindicator-0.1 gnome-applets gnome-control-center
…
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 58 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: ugh! I've been stuck working on these darn windows machines (where * just means "and anything after") for way too long!

Comment: The `*` does work as a wildcard for bash like in DOS, but some commands like `apt-get` expect a regex. When you type `sudo apt-get remove -s k3b*`, bash will first look for any files in your current directory that begin with `k3b`. If it finds any, it will replace that argument with those filenames. If not, it will pass `k3b*` directly to `apt-get`, which will interpret it as a regex. If you don't want bash to interpret the asterisk as a wildcard first (which you probably don't), surround the argument with single quotes, like this: `sudo apt-get remove -s 'k3b*'`

Comment: So the intended command would have been `sudo apt-get remove -s 'k3b.*'`. Just stumbled upon this answer and find it really important to know. IMHO this is quite unexpected and I would quite mark it as a "unexpected behavior" bug of apt-get... you normally expect a "glob" meaning and not a "regexp" meaning if not specified. Thanks anyway and +1!

Comment: And for those like me who didn't know: the `-s` option means "simulation". It tells `apt-get` not to perform the operation, but simply to inform you of what would happen without the `-s` option.

Comment: I think that your use of single quotes to create globbing does NOT work, at least in puppet. And that  *is* unexpected. In 'find' program, if I write find / -iname 'project*' I will find everything that begins with project, not something that has 'project' in it and anything after it. As proof regarding puppet, notice how my results say 'regex', and the results prove it?

Comment: (shortened)Note, selecting 'puppet' for regex 'puppet*'
Note, selecting 'mcollective-plugins-puppetd' for regex 'puppet*'
Note, selecting 'puppetmaster-common' for regex 'puppet*'
Note, selecting 'mcollective-plugins-puppetral' for regex 'puppet*'
Note, selecting 'puppet-testsuite' for regex 'puppet*'
...Note, selecting 'vim-puppet' for regex 'puppet*'
Note, selecting 'puppetmaster' for regex 'puppet*'
Note, selecting 'puppet-lint' for regex 'puppet*'
Note, selecting 'etherpuppet' for regex 'puppet*'
Package etherpuppet is not installed, so not removed

Comment: @Flimm `sudo apt-get remove -s k3b*` and `sudo apt-get remove -s 'k3b*'` are both extremely dangerous and should not be used. If they work it is only because there don't happen to be packages installed that accidentally match the pattern. If the shell doesn't expand `k3b*`, `apt-get` matches it *as a regex* against *any part* any package name. Since `k3b*` is a regex that means "`k`, then `3`, then *zero or more occurrences of `b`*," the result is that `apt-get` attempt to remove every package with `k3` anywhere in its name (not just at the start or with `b`) and packages that depend on them!

Comment: So just to be clear here, `apt list package*` is interpreted as a wildcard, while `sudo apt-get remove package*` is a regex which can match any part of a package string? Why would a package manager be designed with a deathtrap like this?

Answer (score 13):

**Use `sudo apt-get remove ^k3b` instead.** When you install or remove packages, `*` is often dangerous and rarely needed. If you do use `*`, you should quote it, but that does *not* make it safer, because its tendency to select far more packages than you intend is the result of the way `apt` and `apt-get` interpret it and *not* an effect of [pathname expansion](https://foldoc.org/glob).

- Even [safe uses of `*`](https://askubuntu.com/a/513522/22949) are [often unnecessary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why#comment1511867_513522).
- Unsafe uses [are brutal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/how-to-fix-ubuntu-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages). Removing `k3b*` removes every package that contains `k3` *anywhere* in its name (and every package that depends on such a package). That's not a typo--containing `k3` is sufficient, even without the `b`, because `b*` means "zero or more `b`s."

---

When you run [`apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html) or [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) with the `install`, `remove`, or `purge` action, each subsequent argument is first<sup>**1**</sup> interpreted as the name of an individual package. If a package with that exact name exists, the action is performed for it.

If there is no such package, `apt` and `apt-get` will check if the argument contains any of the common [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) [metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)<sup>**2**</sup> [`.`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), [`?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), [`+`, `*`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [`|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [`\[`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [`^`, or `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). If not, it's done--no package was found.

If it *does* contain any of those characters, then it is treated as a regular expression and matched against *any part* of any package name. It doesn't have to match the whole name. As others have said, `*` in a regular expression doesn't mean the same thing as `*` in a glob. `?` doesn't either. In a regular expression:

- `*` allows the previous item to appear [any number of times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)--including just once or not at all--instead of exactly once.
- `?` makes the previous item [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)--that is, it allows it to appear zero or one times.

[apt-get(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) (`man apt-get`) says:

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains
>   one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular
>   expression, and it is applied to all package names in the database.
>   Any matches are then installed (or removed). Note that matching is
>   done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and 'lowest'. If this is
>   undesired, anchor the regular expression with a '^' or '$' character,
>   or create a more specific regular expression.

The manpage only mentions `.`, `?`, and `*`, but *it is incomplete*, as `+`, `|`, `[`, `^`, and `$` are also sufficient to let `apt-get` or `apt` interpret the pattern as a regular expression.<sup>**3**</sup>

**Although you can match any number of any characters with `.*`--*not* just `*`--you only need this if it would appear in the *middle* of your regular expression.** Because the pattern is matched against any substring of a package name, it's pointless at the end (or beginning) of the pattern.

The manpage mentions [`^` and `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). These (especially `^`) are key to writing safe, efficient patterns for use with the `install`, `remove`, or `purge` actions in `apt` or `apt-get`.

- `^` anchors a regular expression to the *beginning* of the whole string. `^k3b` selects all packages whose names *start* with `k3b`.
- `$` anchors a regular expression to the *end* of the whole string. `k3b$` would select all packages whose names *end* with `k3b`.

Therefore you can use this command to safely remove the packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove ^k3b
```

Finally, in the specific case you mentioned, you might as well just pass both names yourself:

```
sudo apt-get remove k3b k3b-data
```

Then you avoid all this complexity! (Though anchoring with `^` is simple once you're used to it.) Or use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion), which your shell expands into the above command:

```
sudo apt-get remove k3b{,-data}
```

---

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>There are two exceptions to this: *(a)* some options (e.g., `-f`, `--purge`) are recognized, and  *(b)* some punctuation characters appearing at the *end* of an argument that would otherwise be taken as a package name to perform the action can be used to alter what is done (e.g., `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` installs the [task](https://askubuntu.com/a/249373/22949) rather than the package, and when `^` appears at the end ).</sub>

<sup>**2**</sup> <sub>Other regular expression metacharacters exist. For example, `\` is supported by all dialects of regular expressions and commonly used. `.`, `?`, `+`, `*`, `|`, `[`, `^`, and `$` just happen to be the metacharacters the APT developers decided would trigger interpretation as a regular expression (after resolution as an exact package named has failed).</sub>

<sup>**3**</sup> <sub>The easiest way to verify this is to simulate installation or removal with such a pattern, using the `-s` option as described above. For example, running `apt -s install ^virtualbox` shows that `sudo apt install ^virtualbox` would have the effect of attempting to install every package the package manager knows about whose name begins with `virtualbox`. However, this behavior can also be verified by examining [the source code](https://git.launchpad.net/apt/tree/?h=1.2.y). Check the `CacheSetHelper::PackageFromRegEx` function in [`cacheset.cc`](https://git.launchpad.net/apt/tree/apt-pkg/cacheset.cc?h=1.2.y).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You more then likely remove a lib that had k3b in it that those programs depended on.

In short you may never know. I recommend not using a wildcard to remove things and to read things when prompted (sorry).

Also with out the -n regex searches use all fields and not just names

http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/man/man8/apt-cache.8.html

also qbi is correct your regex is flawed from the get-go

Comment: One other thing, In cases like yours (k3b and k3b data) just apt-get uninstall k3b. Apt will then inform you if you have things installed that you no longer need, and what you need to do to remove them.

Comment: wow! I never would have expected it to search within descriptions too! yeah, this is definitely something I'll never do again! (and I'll be sure to read things next time :P)

Comment: The link is broken, would you mind clarifying how to use the -n?

Comment: -n means only search in the names field.

Comment: After trying, the -n option is not recognized by `apt-get remove`, only by `apt-get cache`. It seems that actually, `apt-get remove` only looks for package names, not descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Use .* instead of *, and put inside quotes ' '

```
sudo apt-get remove 'k3b.*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt search` which has the advantage of searching in both package names and package descriptions But it is also a bit **dangerous**. for example, if you want to remove any package related to `MY_PATTERN` you can run:

```sh
sudo apt search MY_PATTERN | grep "^[^\ ]*/" -o | sed 's/\///' | xargs -I '{}' sudo apt remove -y '{}'
```

**BE CAUTIOUS:** Don't use **small** search patterns that can be found in many words like `he, and,...`. it might cause non-related package removal and therefore corruption. Before run check out the output of the `apt search MY_PATTERN` first.

`apt search MY_PATTERN`: Find the pattern in the package names and package descriptions on the remote repositories.

`grep "^[^\ ]*/" -o`: extract the package name.

`sed 's/\///'`: remove `/` from the extracted names.

`xargs -I '{}' sudo apt remove -y '{}'`: remove one by one.