# How to remove redmine from ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, redmine

Log:

```
:/opt/maven$ sudo apt-get -f install redmine-sqlite 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 redmine-mysql : Depends: redmine (= 2.2.0+dfsg1-1~precise+1) but 2.1.4+dfsg2-2~precise+2 is to be installed
 redmine-sqlite : Depends: ruby-sqlite3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: redmine (= 2.2.2+dfsg1-1~precise+1) but 2.1.4+dfsg2-2~precise+2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do I remove redmine and others causing this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Redmine 2.x isn't packaged for Ubuntu in the main repositories. Please elaborate more on what sources you used to install these. Provide the output of `apt-cache policy redmine*` to clarify the current state of your system a bit more. Do this by *editing* your question.

Comment: We can probably close this as a duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/22949). [rick's answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/221399/22949) directly addresses cases like these where the solution is to remove a package. Some of the other answers to that question may be helpful also.

Answer (score 4):

You can uninstall redmine as described in previous answer but it may not remove everything so I would suggest that you first:

`sudo apt-get purge redmine*`

This will remove all things redmine from your system. Then to give it a bit of a clean up after it has been removed also run this:

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Also see this Ubuntu forum post:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=140920

Comment: Probably will work, but please read http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why ; the correct command is `sudo apt-get purge "readmine.*"`. Your command (if there are not files matching `readmine*` in the current directory) will remove all packages starting with "readmin" --- not "readmine".