# Why doesn't usage of '*' always work on zsh?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I ran the following command on zsh

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox*
```

It produced an error, when I ran the same command in bash it worked. Why does this happen?

How can I make the above command work on zsh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Here's what happens

Bash will try to evaluate the pattern `rhythmbox*` on the current working directory. As it is very unlikely there will be any file or directory starting with the sequence of `rhythmbox`, it will not expand, but Bash will provide it as an argument to `apt-get` here.

Note that if you have a file there with the name `rhythmbox-test` then it won't work as it will be expanded and `rhythmbox-test` will be provided as the argument to `apt-get`.

#### Solution: escape or quote it!

So, to reliably use the patters in `apt-get` in a Bash shell, you should always escape it. Use quotes or the backslash, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox\*
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install "rhythmbox*"
```

About the same goes for zsh.

The expansion of the pattern is called [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

#### Demo

```
touch aa ab  # creates files aa and ab
ls a*        # lists both files as Bash provided ls two arguments.
ls 'a*'      # No such file or directory. Bash provided literally a* to ls.
ls a\*       # No such file or directory. Same as above.
```

Comment: It works in [tag:bash], unless `nullglob` or `failglob` is set.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Of course globbing options can change the behaviour of Bash in this. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use quotes to prevent zsh from expanding the '*' (you want apt-get to expand the * )

```
sudo apt-get install "rhythmbox*"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use `^rhythmbox` instead (with `^`).** Usually avoid `*` when installing or removing packages.

Even if you [quote it](https://askubuntu.com/a/313001/22949) so the shell [passes it unchanged](https://askubuntu.com/a/313003/22949), `*` doesn't do what most people expect when it appears in a package name with most `apt`/`apt-get` actions, including `install`, `remove`, and `purge`. Avoid `*` in the pattern that follows these actions unless you know precisely what it does and why. Usually `*` is not what you actually want and this is one  of those times when it seems you do not. **`*` does *not* mean "any characters" in this context.**

The proper way to tell `apt-get` to install all packages whose names *start* with `rhythmbox` is:

```
sudo apt-get install ^rhythmbox
```

This also works with `apt install`. Similarly, if you needed to remove such packages, you could specify `^rhythmbox` after the `remove` or `purge` action.

`^rhythmbox` matches all package names that *start* with `rhythmbox` because [`^` is the start-of-line (or, in this case, start-of-string) anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

---

The problem with `*` in the name of a package to install or remove is that
`apt` and `apt-get` [interpret it as a regular expression rather than a glob](https://askubuntu.com/a/431614/22949). In a regular expression, [`*` means "zero or more of the preceding item."](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) So when you run `sudo apt-get install` with `rhythmbox\*`, `'rhythmbox*'`, `"rhythmbox*"`, or (when the shell doesn't expand `*`) `rhythmbox*`, you are actually telling `apt-get` to install every package with `rhythmbo` anywhere in its name.

- Not `rhythmbox`, `rhythmbo`, because the `x` is to appear any number of times--zero or more times.
- Not at the *beginning* of the name, or as the whole name, but *anywhere* in its name.

In the specific case of *this* particular package, this will likely not cause huge problems, as there are probably few packages that have `rhythmbo` in their names but don't start with `rhythmbox`. **But with packages whose names are shorter, especially when using the `remove` or `purge` actions, [this is often disastrous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why).**

---

The main exception to this is `apt list`. The `list` action *does* interpret `*` and `?` as [globbing](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/glob.7.html) characters rather than as regular expression metacharacters. So you can *search* for packages whose names start with `rhythmbox` like this:

```
apt list rhythmbox\*
```

(Or with `'rhythmbox*'` or `"rhythmbox*"`.)

But to *install* such packages--and not install more packages than you mean to--you still need to use:

```
sudo apt install ^rhythmbox
```

Or you can just pass the specific package names you need. Using `apt list` can help you find them.