# Why does apt removes unwanted packages when giving * as suffix?

Tags: apt

I did a `sudo apt-get remove ruby*` and then I saw that some grub packages were being removed too so I went to installed back those packages which log showed to have removed

I set grub to work on my `/sda` (in general, not any number) when was installing back.

Should all be ok or should I fear for my system and plan installing/reconfiguring more of grub.

And, why did this happpen?

Comment: Apt-get works with regular expressions, which means that `ruby*` selects all packages that contain _rub_ in their name. The correct way to remove all packages starting with _ruby_ is: `apt-get remove ^ruby`.

Comment: Related: [How to fix Ubuntu after accidentally uninstalling many packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/how-to-fix-ubuntu-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command on terminal,

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

It will reinstall grub2 on your disk.

If you want to configure your grub then install `grub-pc` package.Try the below command to install `grub-pc` package,

```
sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```

**Note:** Install this package only if you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

Comment: Even if I already did some other grub packages install (same which were removed)?

Comment: Are you installed Ubuntu in legacy mode?post the output of `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"` command.

Comment: `Legacy boot on HDD`

Comment: Install `grub-pc` package to configure your grub.Run this command to install grub-pc package, `sudo apt-get install grub-pc`

Comment: I will do and trust, and by the way:

Why would `sudo apt-get remove ruby*` end up removing grub packages?

(I suggest you to post right on the answer)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu you answered for [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431604/why-does-apt-removes-unwanted-packages-when-giving-as-suffix/431605?noredirect=1#comment560377_431605) comment only, i think.

Comment: Don't step back Raj :P
And btw it worked, thanks so much!

Comment: @diegoaguilar see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431604/why-does-apt-removes-unwanted-packages-when-giving-as-suffix/431605?noredirect=1#comment560592_431605) comment.I don't know what to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13475/discussion-between-diegoaguilar-and-avinash-raj)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't know exactly what you are doing, you should not use:

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove package.*
#                          ⤷ or any other character in the place of dot
```

as this can delete unintended packages and cause more problems than it solves. The `package.*` will match all packages (and their dependencies) containing the string `package` in their name. This is from `man apt-get`, somewhere at the line 110:

> ```
>        If no package matches the given expression and the expression
>        contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX
>        regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the
>        database. Any matches are then installed (or removed). Note that
>        matching is done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and
>        'lowest'. If this is undesired, anchor the regular expression with
>        a '^' or '$' character, or create a more specific regular
>        expression.
> ```

And this is from [Regular Expressions/POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) Wikibooks:

> `*`   Matches the preceding element zero or more times. For example, `ab*c` matches "*ac*", "*abc*", "*abbbc*", etc. `[xyz]*` matches "", "*x*", "*y*", "*z*", "*zx*", "*zyx*", "*xyzzy*", and so on. `\(ab\)*` matches "", "*ab*", "*abab*", "*ababab*", and so on.

Anyway, if you really want to run something like `sudo apt-get remove package.*` (or `sudo apt-get remove packagey*`, or `sudo apt-get remove packagec*` - all are in this case the same), **first run it with `-s` (`--simulate`) option to see exactly what it will do** (see `man apt-get` for more info).

Now, I think that you can solve your problem using the following two steps:

1. [**Reinstall all the packages that you have removed**](https://askubuntu.com/q/50622/147044)
2. Remove only `ruby`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove ruby
   ```

   Or, if you want to remove all packages starting their names with `ruby`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove ^ruby
   ```

   But better to simulate first with:

   ```
   apt-get -s remove ^ruby
   ```

Comment: So it's all about dependencies...

Comment: +1 for the widely unknown `-s` option.

Comment: `package*` will also behave in surprising ways if run from a directory containing any files starting with `package`. Better to quote it: `'package*'`

Answer (score 4):

Apt-get works with regular expressions, which means that `ruby*` selects all packages that contain *rub* in their name. The correct way to remove all packages starting with *ruby* is:

```
apt-get remove ^ruby
```

Comment: +1 from me, but can you explain why **`ruby*` selects all packages that contain *rub* in their name** and not *ruby* as many may think so?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu In a regexp, `y*` means "zero or more `y`s."

Comment: @EliahKagan Personally,I know that; see [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/431614/147044)... :D

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, this is the exact reason why I posted this as a comment, rather than as an answer. I'm not going to write how regular expressions work, sorry.