# Gtx 770 not recognized on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

- GA Z170-HD3P-mobo
- Intel 6500 3.2 - CPU
- NVIDIA Gtx 770 - GPU
- 250GB SATA - hard drive
- 750W - PSU
- some fans
- OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Although I've read that all the hardware is compatible, Ubuntu is not recognizing the GPU and when I go to the NVIDIA GEFORCE website for the most recent driver for this card and run the file it tells me that there was an error in the Text to run the file.

After attempting to install through ppa, i see a list of drivers in the "Software and Updates" to choose from. all binary drivers, however after selecting one and trying to apply the changes, when done the changes are not made and it is still stuck "using X.Org X server-Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(open source)"

may i ask for some assistance on what i should do next?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Is your issue driver related? Can you link to a site you followed a tutorial from?

Comment: Your question is attracting close votes because you do not specifically state what problem you are having. Please edit your question and give specifics.

Comment: Why did you edit this and not give any more information? I can likley help you with this right now but I need to know what the issue is exactly. Is it a boot loop? Black Screen? Driver issue? You need to help us help you, you card is 100% compatable with Ubuntu.

Comment: @null Kirby: yes in the text it states for compatibility. and the issue i am havin to be more specific is that Ubuntu is not recognizing the GPU and  when i go to the NVIDIA GEFORCE website for the most recent driver that would be associated for it to work, when i run the file it tells me that there was an error in the Text to run the file.

Comment: to further add to this that there is no supporting documentation either on youtube or many ways i have tried to research the problem. i know you dont know me but i like to do as much as i can with what i have before i go and ask to risk inevitable confrontation

Comment: okay i just need a walk through on what i need to do. one thing at a time so we can trouble shoot as we go any and all help is appreciated. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to download the drivers for the Nvidia website, this is not Windows.

First, make sure any partly installed driver is removed, run

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

Then reboot and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-375
```

Now reboot again and your driver is installed.

You claim, this is not documented but it is, please have a search around [our FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=frequent), you will find almost all the basics have been coverd, including this.

Comment: alright, the most recent driver on the NVIDIA  website is that 384.90 not 375 so how am i supposed to know that the driver you mentioned is not an older driver that may not even work. furthermore it states for other GPUs, not for the 770 in particular. assistance without sass will suffice. thank you greatly. i will see if this does the trick.

Comment: It is the current stable driver, why would it not work. What sass? I answerd your question. This has been answerd so many times and I won't recive votes for this, I was throwing you a bone here by wrighting this answer for you, do not throw it back in my face.

Comment: "You claim, this is not documented but it is, please have a search around our FAQ, you will find almost all the basics have been coverd, including this."  as previously stated "any and all help is greatly appreciated" by your truly. thank you for your help. if i could throw votes at you i would.out of the goodness of your heart i thank you and i hope you continue to expand other peoples knowledge as you have mine.

Comment: the "sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-375" command states "E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-375"

Comment: Sorry, it should just be `sudo apt install nvidia-375`

Comment: if lets say that the connection times out. for whatever reason that do i have to purge and do it again?

Comment: Just run the install command again, connection timeout may be because a server is down for whatever reason. If it says it is already install and an error, then purge it first.

Comment: okay i let it finish doing what it was supposed to do. it said that the new packages were installed. however i rebooted and the graphics is still coming from the Gallium 0.4 on NVE4

Comment: @MarkKirby What's the goal of `sudo apt purge nvidia*`? Bash performs filename expansion on `nvidia*` if it can (if the OP downloaded nvidia files, that's likely), which you don't want. If not expanded, `nvidia*` is passed to `apt` as if you ran `sudo apt purge 'nvidia*'`. But you don't want that either: [`apt` treats it as a regex](https://askubuntu.com/a/210980) so `a*` means "zero or more `a`s." This matches all packages with `nvidi` anywhere in their names. If the goal is to remove packages [whose names *start*](https://askubuntu.com/a/519053) with `nvidia`, use `sudo apt purge ^nvidia`.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for the tip, it is not something I know a lot about but I will for sure look in to it on your advice.