# Remove all development libraries

Tags: uninstall, development, libraries

I've built a few apps from source which required development libraries. And when I installed them, they installed more `-dev` dependencies.

Now I want to remove those libraries.

The command `sudo apt-get purge lib*-dev` can do any harm to my Ubuntu installation?

Are there any development libraries included in a fresh install of Ubuntu? If there are, should I keep them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you don't need any development libraries to run your system. As the name says, they are for development purposes. The libraries used to run these applications are different ones.

Your command looks fine to me, but anyway APT is giving you a list with the packages to be removed. Just watch it for packages you need (everything without the `-dev` would be suspicious)

Comment: Yes, I know the apps don't need them anymore after they are built.

Comment: Also APT will warn you if you may destroy your system. ("You are about to do something potentially dangerous....")

Answer (score 1):

Token from https://askubuntu.com/a/1277984/1621404

This removes everything with "-dev" in name,

```
sudo apt list --installed -a '*-dev' | grep "^[^\ ]*/" -o | sed 's/\///' | xargs -I '{}' sudo apt remove -y '{}'
```