# Revert AMD graphic drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, ubuntu-drivers

I've installed AMD graphic drivers and rebooted my system. Now when i'm logging in my screen turns off or shows a lot of noise in different colors, but i cant see anything. That means i cant use my Xubuntu insalled on HDD. I've live USB Stick, how to revert installation using Live USB? Or maybe nay other possibilities?

Comment: @Rmano Is there possibility to log on my HDD Xubuntu from Live USB Stick?

Comment: You can boot in console only mode probably even without the USB disk --- follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it booting with options `nomodeset single`, or boot into recovery mode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode

Comment: What if i've got rEFInd boot loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Boot your computer.
2. After it is started, swicth to TTY1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
3. Log in using your normal username and password.
4. run this command to remove the drivers `sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*" "fglrx-amdcccle.*"`
5. run `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` to delete the x.org configuration file.
6. run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64` to re-install x.org.
7. run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` to reconfigure x.org.
8. run `sudo reboot` to reboot.

You can do this from your Xubuntu computer, but you will need to type all these commands in. A lot of this I copy pasted from here: [How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers#68312)

I don't use AMD drivers personally.

Comment: Whichever Command in Passing IT says for lock file var/lib/dpkg/lock only for read lock wont be used,couldnt write to /var/cache /apt

Comment: Make sure you are using sudo when typing in these commands.

Comment: it automatically makes me a root

Comment: If you're root then `apt-get` shouldn't give you that error unless there's something that is already using apt or dpkg.

Comment: WARNING. `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` is **wrong**. You should use `sudo apt-get purge "^fglrx.*"`, it's a regular expression... see http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why

Comment: Found out that i had to mount all devices manually, that was a problem :) Thank you for help

Comment: @Rmano I changed the regular expression to the one that was given in the older AU question I linked to.