# rolling back installed AMD graphics

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

My laptop is R510IU-LSFX with AMD Radeon R7 Graphics Processor.
I installed AMD graphic drivers for ubuntu 18.04 LTS according to [this link](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers)

As it is mentioned in the link, I performed these commands in sequence:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
>
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
>
> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
>
> sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
>
> sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386

Note: I got some "package not found or not downloaded" errors during these commands.(but ignored)

then I rebooted to apply changes. but I faced the screen below which the system was stuck there for hours:
[stuck screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIifG.jpg)

I fortunately solved it by passing 'nomodeset' as command but when I entered Desktop, everything was big.
Here are the things I have done but couldn't solve:

- "Software and updates" --> "Additional Drivers": but no additional drivers available.
- settings --> devices --> display: the only resolution available is 800*600
- i tried the solutions in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539423/revert-amd-graphic-drivers) but i face the response below on first command:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree         Reading state information... Done
>
> Note, selecting 'fglrx-pxpress' for regex 'fglrx.*'
>
> Note, selecting 'fglrx-updates-core' for regex 'fglrx.*'
>
> Note, selecting 'fglrx-glx' for regex 'fglrx.*'
>
> Package 'fglrx-updates-core' is not installed, so not removed
>
> Package 'fglrx-glx' is not installed, so not removed
>
> E: Unable to locate package fglrx-amdcccle.*
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'fglrx-amdcccle.*'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'fglrx-amdcccle.*'

How can i roll back the changes or get the optimal resolution??

I would really really appreciate your help.

Looking for your solutions.

Comment: It sounds like you've had a very similar sunday to what I've had :-)
I recovered by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon` and removing the nomodeset option.
I don't think the flgrx* packages are available in 18.04

Comment: You could try `ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa`, but really, there is no roll back, roll up, or roll anywhere thing in Ubuntu. In case `ppa-purge` doesn't work, reinstall, and next time, think twice before adding testing PPAs.