# Ubuntu without GUI

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, gui

I am using an Ubuntu 12.04 lts and I don't need the GUI, so I changed the grub to start as text mode, but since I don't use the GUI, I want to delete all about it to save space.

I tried "sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop", but there is still the same GUI as before.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think that dependencies are really too tangled to the presence of a desktop for making this thing possible. You can check the remove command in simulation mode, for example:

```
apt-get -s purge ubuntu-desktop whatever more
```

...but in my experience you end deleting too much. BTW, trying to remove `ubuntu-desktop` does nothing because it is just a meta-package; you should remove its dependencies--- you can check them by:

```
[romano:~] % apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop
  Depends: alsa-base
  Depends: alsa-utils
    alsa-utils:i386
  Depends: anacron
 {...awfully lot of lines removed...]
```

and as you can see the dependents are for example the sound system or anacron, which I do not know if you really want to remove... so the only way is going through that list manually and remove what you want (again, simulate before!).

To have a text-only minimal installation I would either:

1. [install a *server* version of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DocumentationTeam/SystemDocumentation/UbuntuServerGuide) --- I think it comes without graphic interface  by default;
2. switch to a distribution more tailored to minimal installation and control (like for example [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners%27_guide)).

...but are you sure is worthwhile? Hard disk is cheap nowadays and you'll going to gain at most a couple of GiB...

Comment: Thanks, I will try to delete all the dependencies that I want.
This Ubuntu is on a System on Module, so the memory is very small, that is why I want to remove as much as possible.

Comment: server version of Ubuntu == 800 MB. Thanks lol)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all the GUI libs, X, pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get purge "^libgtk.*" "^libqt.*" xserver-xorg-core "^pulseaudio.*"
```

Then do an autoremove to remove left over dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

I am using purge to remove config files as well.

Check the list of packages to be removed, sometimes you get unexpected dependencies for CLI tools.

Comment: Wrong command usage. Should be `sudo apt-get purge "^libgtk.*" ...`. `apt-get` accepts a regexp, not a glob. Horror story: http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why

Comment: Good spot, Stuck in Windows mode. Fixed.

Comment: Why do you remove the printing system too? And... have you tried it? I checked a simulation with `apt-get -s purge` (simulation mode) and it will remove way too much (python for example...)

Comment: Cause its something I remove as I don't use printing... fixed :)
According to the sim python stays on my machine.