# Compile error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL collect2

Tags: sdl

When I do

```
$ gcc cube.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lSDL 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I do

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsdl*
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libsdl-image1.2 is already the newest version.
libsdl-image1.2 set to manually installed.
libsdl1.2debian is already the newest version.
libsdl1.2debian set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdformat-dev : Depends: libboost-regex-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: liburdfdom-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libsdl-image1.2-dev : Depends: libtiff-dev
 libsdl-mixer1.2-dev : Depends: libflac-dev (>= 1.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbis-dev (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libsdl1.2-dbg : Depends: libsdl1.2debian (= 1.2.15-8ubuntu1) but 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libsdl1.2debian (= 1.2.15-8ubuntu1) but 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libudev-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

It seems libsdl installation was not successful.  While searching about libsdl there are two versions libsdl1 and libsdl2.  I am thinking to find some other ways to install them.  Anyone have any advice for the installation?

@steeldriver:I did your suggestion and the output was the followings:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
finished...

$ sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libsdl1.2debian (= 1.2.15-8ubuntu1) but 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

A.B. as you requested.  Here is output of commands in your comment.

When I did

```
$ apt-cache policy libsdl1.2-dev
libsdl1.2-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.15-8ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.2.15-8ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.mirror.crucial.com.au/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

When I did

```
$ apt-cache policy libsdl1.2debian
libsdl1.2debian:
  Installed: 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.15-8ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.mirror.crucial.com.au/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

When I did

```
$ apt-cache policy libpulse-dev
libpulse-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:4.0-0ubuntu11
  Version table:
     1:4.0-0ubuntu11 0
        500 http://ubuntu.mirror.crucial.com.au/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

A.B.: When I did.  Downgrade happened.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian=1.2.15-8ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libsdl1.2debian
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 162 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libsdl1.2debian
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 http://ubuntu.mirror.crucial.com.au/ trusty/main libsdl1.2debian amd64 1.2.15-8ubuntu1 [162 kB]
Fetched 162 kB in 0s (243 kB/s)     
dpkg: warning: downgrading libsdl1.2debian:amd64 from 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1 to 1.2.15-8ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 443054 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsdl1.2debian_1.2.15-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15-8ubuntu1) over (1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15-8ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

Solved by doug's suggestion

```
Open up Software & Updates > Updates tab & make sure that 
the first 2 are enabled. (- trusty-security, trusty-updates). 
If one or the other wasn't enabled then do so, 
after that reload sources & proceed.
```

Thanks for your solution, doug!  Thanks to all who participated in this problem especially steeldriver and A.B.!

Comment: It looks like your system has a mix of trusty and trusty-updates packages: have you tried  doing a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` cycle to try to get your packages in sync, and the `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev`?

Comment: Btw, remember that using `*` in `apt` commands do not mean what you seem to think:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why

Comment: @Rmano: I followed guidance on https://tutorialsplay.com/opengl/2014/04/23/textured-cube/

Comment: @steeldriver: thanks for suggeston.  but still the same...I pasted output of  terminal on question.

Comment: Do you have any PPAs enabled, that might be holding back those packages?

Comment: That page is wrong too.... It can work but only by chance

Comment: @Rmano: Which part is wrong?  I am a first time OpenGL learner.  If you can tell a website explains step by step from setup enviornment to run codes.  It would be more than welcome...

Comment: I am not referring to OpenGL. I was speaking about the `apt-get` command. For what you want to do, the correct command is `apt-get install 'libsdl.*'`; `apt-get` needs a regular expression, not a glob pattern. In this case it will probably making no difference, though; it can have messed things before. Have you tried a `apt-get install -f` to see if it can sort out the dependency knot?

Comment: @Rmano: I tried with libsdl.* still output remain unchanged.  I found that the command alright I tried with a livedisc it worked.  I also tried to install a dependency package individually as well.  In fact it is more on my system issue accessing repository as there are no such a package to install at the end.  If I install libpulse-dev then I would get another dependency package and so on.  Dig down ends up reaching package not available.

Comment: @steeldriver: You mean under preferences -> Other software ->[ ] PPA's ? If so I have a lot of lines of them.  I just executed commands sudo rm -if /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* to clean them all.  But still getting unmet dependencies for libsdl1.2debian and libpulse-dev when I executed install libsdl1.2-dev.  I am suspecting on my system issue because when I tried with a livedisc worked just perfect.  Can you tell what else I can do?  I remember I did not get dependency error before.  Dependency issue first appeared when update something from software center which I cannot recall now...

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of `apt-cache policy libsdl1.2-dev`, `apt-cache policy libsdl1.2debian`, `apt-cache policy libpulse-dev`

Comment: @A.B.: I put up the output of those commands on my question.  Please take a look :-) Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian=1.2.15-8ubuntu1`

Comment: @A.B.: Thanks for your reply.  I put up the output of the command on my question. Please take a look :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up Software & Updates > Updates tab & make sure that the first 2 are enabled. (- trusty-security, trusty-updates). If one or the other wasn't enabled then do so, after that  reload sources & proceed.

If both where then try switching severs on main page > Download from: use main server. Then reload sources & see.

You need libsdl1.2-dev (1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1) to be available & it should be, was released in 04/14 - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libsdl1.2-dev

Comment: `libsdl1.2-dev (1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1) ` is installed, see the question

Answer (score -2):

Try something like `gcc cube.c $(pkg-config --libs glut gl glu sdl)`. Not totally sure about those package names though.