# fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory

Tags: opengl, sdl

I am trying to practice lesson_1 at 
https://tutorialsplay.com/opengl/2014/04/23/textured-cube/

When I run the code named cube.c I got

```
cube.c:16:21: fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL/SDL.h>
                     ^

compilation terminated.
```

I've installed SDL2 with guidance at 
https://github.com/PluginIO/EX3/wiki/Setting-up-SDL2-in-Ubuntu-12.10

I am using 14.04 though..

The installation of SDL2 was successful I did not get any error.

The SDL.h file is located in "/usr/local/include/SDL2"

I tried to force to use fullpath linking by command

```
gcc cube.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU -l/usr/local/include/SDL2
```

instead of

```
gcc cube.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lSDL
```

But all were in vain...

Does anybody know solution for this linking problem?

As what muru pointed out I changed to captial i got "error: unknown type name ‘SDL_keysym’" meaning worked.

Other way I discovered was

I changed

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

to

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

No longer shows "fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory"
Thus for now consider solved.
However I am getting the following errors that will be posting on separate thread.

```
cube.c:105:22: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_keysym’
 void handleKeyPress( SDL_keysym *keysym )
                      ^
cube.c: In function ‘main’:
cube.c:239:5: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_VideoInfo’
     const SDL_VideoInfo *videoInfo;
     ^
```

A.B.: I pasted output of your suggested commands below.

```
gcc cube.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl`
Package sdl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sdl' found



gcc cube.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
cube.c:105:22: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_keysym’
 void handleKeyPress( SDL_keysym *keysym )
                      ^
cube.c: In function ‘main’:
cube.c:239:5: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_VideoInfo’
     const SDL_VideoInfo *videoInfo;
     ^
errors continue....
```

Comment: `-l` is a linker option. To add include directories, use `-I` (capital i). Also, why didn't you just install [`libsdl1.2-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libsdl1.2-dev/filelist)?

Comment: @muru: Thanks for the pointing that out.  I changed to captial i got "error: unknown type name ‘SDL_keysym’"
meaning worked.  I will post the errors on separate thread. Your second question's answer is at http://askubuntu.com/questions/626230/compile-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lsdl-collect2

Comment: @muru: can you post your solution to the answer?  So that I can select the asnwer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably you have already installed the libraries, I show the steps but again for the reason of completeness.

- SDL2

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
  ```
- SDL1

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
  ```

Start the compilation with:

- SDL2

  ```
  gcc cube.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
  ```
- SDL1

  ```
  gcc cube.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl`
  ```

---

Sample output:

```
% pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl               
-D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL -lSDL

% pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2
```

Comment: Thank for your answer A.B.! Actually I am having issue with install libsdl1 and 2. Please comment on  http://askubuntu.com/questions/626230/compile-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lsdl-collect2  I pasted output of your suggestion on question.

Comment: for me sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev worked not the former :) Thanks!