# VirtualBox 5.0 installation has broken VirtualBox packages on Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, 15.04

Seeing that there was a new VirtualBox release, I tried to install it on Kubuntu 15.04...

However, now all of my VBox 4.3 packages in the ubuntu repositories are broken (Virtualbox is provided by Virtualbox-5.0 which is not installed), and VirtualBox 5.0 won't work as it says DKMS is broken:

```
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules/etc/init.d/vboxdrv: 302: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: /usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost/do_dkms: not found
 ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS/etc/init.d/vboxdrv: 327: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: /usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost/do_dkms: not found
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
```

Reinstalling virtualbox-dkms:

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 4.3.26-dfsg-2ubuntu2); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-5.0 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
```

Even though VirtualBox 5.0 was installed via deb package from the Oracle website.

What can I do to either completely remove 5.0 and install VirtualBox 4.3, or correctly install virtualbox 5.0?

I've already tried uninstalling VirtualBox 5.0 (via apt-get purge), then installing 4.3, but get the error relating to VirtualBox being provided by the package virtualbox-5.0.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove **older** VirtualBox **versions** before installing VirtualBox-5.0 !

Uninstall VirtualBox -> `sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"`

Carefully check what will be removed (before you confirm it).

Update the software repositories -> `sudo apt-get update`

Clean up -> `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean`

Download and register the ORACLE public key ->

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the VirtualBox repo to the software sources ->

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
```

Now update the software repositories again -> `sudo apt-get update`

Install VirtualBox -> `sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-5.0`

**Note for other users who use a newer Ubuntu edition than 15.04 :**

As of Ubuntu 16.04 the ORACLE public key to download has  changed.

`oracle_vbox.asc` has to be replaced with `oracle_vbox_2016.asc`

Comment: Be careful with the `*` and `apt-get`: this command accepts a regular expression, **not** a glob-pattern!. Your command should be `apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"`. In this case is probably the same, but it *will* bite you... see http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why

Comment: @Rmano - thanks for your comment. I checked the sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-* command. Result was virtualbox only and suggestion to autoremove  libsdl-ttf afterwards, which was installed as a dependency together with virtualbox. Main reason to take this specific command was to be sure that nothing of the former virtualbox installation would remain. Anyway I take your warning seriously, so I added "Check carefully what will be removed before you confirm" to my answer.

Comment: @Rmano was correct... Using a regex worked for me where * did not, it initially said it couldn't find the virtualbox-5.0.2... package.

Comment: @BnMcG --- that was probably because you issued the command from the directory where you had the `virtualbox-5.0.2...` `.deb` package. Without the quotes, shell expansion took precedence, and the `*` was substituted before `apt-get` had a chance to see it.

Comment: Here is the link to the official manual describing proposed approach for all debian-based distributions: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions

Answer (score 6):

My Virtualbox does not work. It starts but could not execute any of the machines. The solution I found was:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

and then:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```