# How do I make space on /boot?

Tags: boot, kernel, cleanup

How do I free up space on /boot?

```
ls /boot/

    abi-4.2.0-16-generic         memtest86+.bin
    abi-4.2.0-19-generic         memtest86+.elf
    abi-4.2.0-22-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
    config-4.2.0-16-generic      System.map-4.2.0-16-generic
    config-4.2.0-19-generic      System.map-4.2.0-19-generic
    config-4.2.0-22-generic      System.map-4.2.0-22-generic
    efi                          vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
    grub                         vmlinuz-4.2.0-19-generic
    initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-19-generic.efi.signed
    initrd.img-4.2.0-19-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic
    initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic.efi.signed
    lost+found
```

I am very novice user. I took a look at: [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot), but the information seemed too complicated for me. I was hoping a simple answer to my specific problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: Why do you need to? The boot partition is pretty tiny, and you kinda need everything in there

Comment: Updates.. it's telling me I need to free up around 40mb I think.

Comment: It looksToo complicated for you? Who installed Ubuntu with a separate and small /boot partition? That was initially a bad idea. It looks like the partition is just enough for 3 kernels. You will have always remove kernels manually as it is explained in the too complicated answer.

Comment: If you manually partition the disk, you commit to be technical enough for it. Otherwise just install Ubuntu with auto partitioning.

Comment: Worth noting that some hosting providers stuck in the dark ages provision servers in rebuilds with really tiny /boot/ partitions, and not in an easily expandable partition.  This is fine for a few updates, but I've seen default builds with 200mb space, which used to be sufficient 10 years ago, however not anymore!

Comment: Or you can use Ubuntu Tweaks. http://askubuntu.com/a/553595/16395

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Might help, it will remove old unused kernel images, but if the `/boot` partition is that small, you may consider resizing it.

Comment: Worth noting that sometimes APT requires space in /boot/ to remove the unused kernels.  Resolvable by running "uname -r" (shows current in-use kernel) and removing ONLY older kernels that are not in use - then running apt-get remove apt-get remove linux-image-4.2.0.*version* --purge

Answer (score 0):

While autoremove will possible clear some space it will not remove older kernels which can still be selected by grub. I check in these cases which kernel I am running with `cat /proc/version`.
Since the version you are running at that moment is boot-able I remove all older kernels using:
`sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.2.0.*version*`
You can use regular expressions in this, so you are probably running 4.2.0-22 and can remove all older. That can be done by:
`sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.2.0-1.*`
(Check for more detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/210976/158442))

**Do not just trow away the files which are not in use, though it will work it will keep on generating grub errors on updates.** Not really harmful but it is annoying.

Comment: `apt-get` doesn't use wildcards, it uses regular expressions.

Comment: Oh? funny, I always presumed it were wildcards but I actually only use the asterisk. Was I always lucky to have a dot in front of the asterisk or just a bit blind; I'll check and update my answer, thanks!.

Comment: Linking to http://askubuntu.com/q/210976/158442 should be enough.