# Shorter way to apt-get install php7.0-{some modules}

Tags: apt, bash, regex, php7

I am currently installing php7.0 and was wondering if there is an shorter way to install the modules. normally I type:

```
    apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt 
     php7.0-phpdbg php7.0-dev php7.0-curl php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-json 
     php7.0-gd php7.0-cli
```

Is there an regular expression so you don't have to type php7.0 over and over again? Something like:

```
   apt-get install php7.0-{fpm mbstring mcrypt phpdbg dev curl sqlite3 
    json gd cli}
```

I searched for something like this for hours but could not find it. In advance thanks for your reply.

Comment: What about `apt-get install php7*`? Short enough? But it will simply install all possible php7 packages.

Comment: @Videonauth worse - it will install all packages containing `php` anywhere in the package name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Videonauth suggested, you can use `apt-get install php7.*` but that will install all packages whose names contain `php7`. To install those whose names starts with `php7`, use `apt-get install '^php7. *`. To instal only those on your list, you can use brace expansion. The format is almost what you already tried: braces but a comma-separated list:

```
$ echo foo{a,b,c}
fooa foob fooc
```

Therefore:

```
$ echo php7.0-{fpm,mbstring,mcrypt,phpdbg,dev,curl,sqlite3,json,gd,cli}
php7.0-fpm php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-phpdbg php7.0-dev php7.0-curl php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-json php7.0-gd php7.0-cli
```

So, you could run:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-{fpm,mbstring,mcrypt,phpdbg,dev,curl,sqlite3,json,gd,cli}
```

Comment: He he, wasn't sure about if those brace expansions will work, so I only commented.

Comment: @Videonauth yup, they do, they just need space. You can also do things like `echo {1..10}` or `echo {01..10}`. Useful stuff.

Comment: No, `php7*` **does not** install packages starting with `php7`. `apt-get` uses regular expressions, not wildcards. Unless you have files named `php7-foo` in your current directory, `php7*` will be passed by the shell to `apt-get`, which will treat it as a regex and match it over the entire package name. So *every package containing `php` in its name* will be selected for installation. People have been bit by this, repeatedly: http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why

Comment: @muru eek! Thanks, I'd forgotten the `.`.

Comment: @terdon not just the `.`, you'll need to anchor the expression with `^`

Comment: @muru true. I was thinking that `php7` was specific enough but you're right, there may be unwanted packages containing the string.