# Removed all files after removing daq* package

Tags: system-installation, backup

[image]

When I tried to remove the `daq*` package of snort my all files got removed from my PC, including system files. Now I want to backup my data from my PC, but I am not able to do anything. The above image shows the output of my current screen. Please help, as this data is very important to me.

Comment: What was the exact command you used? I hope **no** `apt remove daq*` because this does not do what you think: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why --- I would boot with a rescue disk/live image, mount your PC disks, and save the data before doing anything else.