# Why is this package not removed with apt-get remove?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I have:

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
rc  libnvidia-compute-396:i386  396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1  i386 NVIDIA libcompute package
```

When I do:

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libnvidia-*
```

this package is not removed?

Other "libnvidia" package is removed with this command, this one for example:

```
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64   390.48-0ubuntu3      amd64  NVIDIA libcompute package
```

In the remove log it says:

```
Package 'libnvidia-compute-396' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'libnvidia-compute-396:i386'?
```

And when I remove it with full name it gets removed.

Answer (score 4):

Apt (or, rather `dpkg`) operates on the default architecture by, well, default. From the output it looks like `i386` is not your default architecture, so you have to specify it. For example, see [the Debian Multiarch HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO##Installing.2Fremoving_packages), which shows you have to specify the foreign architecture for both installing and removing such packages.

You could do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge 'libnvidia-.*:i386'
```

(Note that apt doesn't use wildcards, but regex. See [apt-get remove with wildcard removed way more than expected. why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/210976/894115))

Comment: I was following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/206289/754424. It looks like the answer should really state "sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-.*" instead of "sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*"? Note the dot before *.

Comment: The way it works is, `apt` matches across the full package name - so if you wanted to remove all packages that had `nvidia` anywhere in the package name, that still works (because the regex `-*` matches the empty string as well).  So that particular mistake might be harmless, but still worth fixing.