# Unable to remove wine

Tags: 18.04, package-management, wine

I tried to remove wine but it says that virtual packages like wine can't be removed. Also I am unable to find my `.wine` file.

Answer (score 7):

To uninstall packages you don't know the name of you have two choices - [use a regex](https://askubuntu.com/a/957466/527764) that will find all matching packages, or find the package name.

#### Matching multiple packages

```
sudo apt remove ^wine
```

This will attempt to remove all packages starting with `wine`. Pay attention and check that the package list does not include any packages you want to keep before you select yes.

#### Search package lists for relevant things

```
dpkg --list | grep wine
```

This will give you a list of packages installed whose names contain the string `wine`. You can manually copy the package names you want to uninstall to a `sudo apt remove` command.