# Can 'sudo apt-get remove [write]' destroy my Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

I wanted to remove my 'write' app, so I found this on a site:
To remove a package type:

```
sudo apt-get remove [package_name]
```

So I typed:

```
sudo apt-get remove [write]
```

And afterwards I agreed on the prompt: 'yes, do what I say!' or something like that. And voila! My Ubuntu was deleting!
Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: A teachable moment about reading the complete output. Many of us have done something similar...once.

Comment: A good tip if you are not sure what will happen is to use the flag `--simulate` or `-s` under `apt` or `apt-get` first - Example: `sudo apt -s remove php7.2-pspell` doesn't actually remove that. Just shows you what would get removed/affected (if installed). Same for 'install'.

Comment: `touch w` first to save yourself some grief ;-).

Comment: @B.Tanner I’m glad to hear that my answer does actually help instead of just polarizing. You’re always welcome in the [AU general chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) in case you have further (or other) questions or just want to say hello!

Comment: Also a good lesson about the notation conventions in man pages.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The correct command to remove a package named `write` is:

```
sudo apt remove write
```

`[write]` is a character set matching the characters “w”, “r”, “i”, “t” and “e” and as matching is done by substring by `apt`. The command you ran thus matched **all packages with one of these characters in it**, which of course are *a lot*. To quote `apt`’s output listing just the essential ones:

```
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt adduser (due to apt) gpgv (due to apt) ubuntu-keyring (due to apt) libapt-pkg5.0 (due to apt) libc6 (due to apt) libgcc1 (due to apt) libgnutls30 (due to apt) libseccomp2 (due to apt)
  libstdc++6 (due to apt) base-files base-passwd libdebconfclient0 (due to base-passwd) bash libtinfo5 (due to bash) debianutils (due to bash) bsdutils libsystemd0 (due to bsdutils) coreutils
  libacl1 (due to coreutils) libattr1 (due to coreutils) libselinux1 (due to coreutils) dash dpkg (due to dash) diffutils libbz2-1.0 (due to dpkg) liblzma5 (due to dpkg) libzstd1 (due to dpkg)
  zlib1g (due to dpkg) tar (due to dpkg) e2fsprogs libblkid1 (due to e2fsprogs) libcom-err2 (due to e2fsprogs) libext2fs2 (due to e2fsprogs) libss2 (due to e2fsprogs) libuuid1 (due to e2fsprogs) fdisk
  libfdisk1 (due to fdisk) libmount1 (due to fdisk) libncursesw5 (due to fdisk) libsmartcols1 (due to fdisk) findutils grep libpcre3 (due to grep) install-info (due to grep) gzip hostname init
  systemd-sysv (due to init) init-system-helpers (due to init) perl-base (due to init-system-helpers) libc-bin login libaudit1 (due to login) libpam0g (due to login) libpam-runtime (due to login)
  libpam-modules (due to login) mount util-linux (due to mount) ncurses-base ncurses-bin sed sysvinit-utils libudev1 (due to util-linux)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2503 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 7238 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

The multiple warnings as well as the necessity to literally type

> Yes, do as I say!

are security means in place to keep you from destroying your system, as the system’s package manager `apt` is perfectly capable of doing that. Any command run with `sudo` should be run carefully and thoughtfully, but don’t fret: Nearly every experienced user of Ubuntu broke their system at least once, in fact that’s part of the fun if you ask me.

#### Further reading

- [this detailed answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/957466/504066) to [apt-get remove with wildcard removed way more than expected. why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/210976/507051)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93501/discussion-on-answer-by-dessert-can-sudo-apt-get-remove-write-destroy-my-ubu).

Answer (score 15):

To add to what other people have said, you will see the syntax that the blogger used in their post quite often.

There are pretty consistent standards that are used when writing documentation on how to use commands. In every manual page, you'll see pretty much the same structure.

If something is **optional**, it is usually in brackets. `ls [folder]` (you don't need to give ls a folder, but you can. Thus, optional).

If something is **a file** or **email**, you will usually see it in angle brackets. `<likeThis.php>`

If you have an **choice between a finite number of things** (i.e Months), you'll see it in braces like this: `{September,October,November,December}`

With any one of these, you may see `...` which denotes that multiple of this can be given.

And finally, if something is absolutely mandatory, you'll see its documentation listed out and probably underlined. For instance, `man mv`, mv's manual, says this:

`mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST`

Technically speaking, the package name (write) isn't a required part of the command. Try it. `apt-get install` or `apt-get remove` will just run and exit the program successfully. That's one reason it could be presented in brackets on that blog.

Answer (score 10):

Before doing an `sudo apt-get`, it is wise to do a simulation:

```bash
$ apt-get remove [write] -s | wc -l
65280
```

There are nearly **65,280** packages that qualify for removal ***if*** installed on your system. `[write]` is a search pattern for  [Regex matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) causing every package to be selected if it contains:

- The letter `w` or `r` or `i` or `t` or `e`

Output is piped to the **Word Count** command with `| wc -l`. Output lines from `apt-get` are suppressed by `wc`. The `-l` switch instructs `wc` to only print count of lines and not word count or character count.

**Simulation** is specified with the `-s` flag. You can also use the `--simulate` flag for greater readability. Another advantage of a simulation is you don't need `sudo` powers which many of us have learned can be dangerous at times.

To get an idea of the package names involved pipe output to the `less` command:

```bash
$ apt-get remove [write] --simulate | less

NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Also keep in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package 'libpam-pin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'activity-log-manager-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnet-patricial-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pe' is not installed, so not removed

   (.... Plus 65,269 more packages ....)
```