# Uninstall a lot of plugins of pidgin

Tags: package-management, uninstall, plugins, software-uninstall, pidgin

So I want to uninstall pidgin. I first ran `sudo apt remove pidgin`. This worked and something was removed. I then ran `apt-cache search pidgin` and I got a lot of plugins that were not removed:

```
pidgin - graphical multi-protocol instant messaging client for X
pidgin-audacious - pidgin integration with Audacious
pidgin-awayonlock - pidgin plugin to set as away on screensaver activation
pidgin-blinklight - Blinks your ThinkPad's ThinkLight upon new messages
pidgin-bot-sentry - pidgin anti spam plugin
pidgin-data - multi-protocol instant messaging client - data files
pidgin-dbg - Debugging symbols for Pidgin
pidgin-dev - multi-protocol instant messaging client - development files
pidgin-encryption - pidgin plugin that provides transparent encryption
pidgin-extprefs - extended preferences plugin for the instant messenger pidgin
pidgin-festival - pidgin plugin to hear incoming messages using voice synthesis
pidgin-gmchess - pidgin integration with gmchess
pidgin-gnome-keyring - integrates pidgin (and libpurple) with the system keyring
pidgin-gnome-keyring-dbg - debugging symbols for pidgin-gnome-keyring
pidgin-guifications - toaster popups for pidgin
pidgin-hotkeys - Configurable global hotkeys for pidgin
pidgin-lastfm - Last.fm plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-latex - Pidgin plugin to display LaTeX formulas
pidgin-libnotify - display notification bubbles in pidgin
pidgin-librvp - MS Exchange RVP instant messaging plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-microblog - Microblogging plugins for Pidgin
pidgin-microblog-dbg - Microblogging plugins for Pidgin (debugging symbols)
pidgin-mpris - sets your available message to your currently playing track
pidgin-mra - Mail.ru Agent protocol plugin for Pidgin IM
pidgin-mra-dbg - Mail.ru Agent protocol plugin for Pidgin IM
pidgin-nateon - Pidgin plugin for NateOn instant messaging service
pidgin-nateon-dbg - debugging symbols of pidgin-nateon
pidgin-openfetion - Fetion protocol plugin for libpurple
pidgin-openpgp - OpenPGP plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-otr - Off-the-Record Messaging plugin for Pidgin
pidgin-plugin-pack - Collection of Pidgin plugins
pidgin-privacy-please - plugin for enhanced privacy in pidgin
pidgin-sipe - Pidgin plugin for MS Office Communicator and MS Lync
```

There are more of them actually.

How do I remove all of these at once?

Also, I remember there being a package manger in Ubuntu which could be used instead of dpkg and apt (It let you install things and you could easily keep track of them). I forgot the name. If someone knows of such software, please comment it.(It's not synaptic and it had its own Ubuntu page explaining how to use it).

Comment: I would suspect that `sudo apt autoremove` would uninstall quite a few of those.

Comment: Tried that initially, but did not work. @Chaale solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

In general, output from APT when removing a single package would tell you if after removing that package, there are other packages that are no longer required and will propose to remove them as well.

I suppose it would be the case if all these plugins where, in fact, installed. Because, `apt-cache search pidgin` will search for any available package: installable **and** already installed.

You could merely use `apt list pidgin*` instead of `apt-cache search pidgin`. The difference is that the former will display `[installed]` next to an installed package that appears on the list.

You could use the following command to remove all (if any) pidgin plugins installed: `sudo apt remove ^pidgin`. (You could also use `sudo apt purge ^pidgin` to completely remove this package).

Regarding the package manager, it's hard to tell, you could be speaking of [Ubuntu Software Center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter). Else, I can't tell.

Comment: To anyone using a wildcard do please read: https://askubuntu.com/a/957466/15811  You should use **^pidgin**

Comment: @Chaale I tried the ```apt list skype*``` which gave me this: ```Listing... Done
skypeforlinux/stable 8.50.0.38 amd64```. But then when I do ```sudo apt remove ^skype```, it says ```skypeforlinux``` not found, so there is nothing to uninstall. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind for precious information. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @GaneshBiradar : you seem to be looking for something else. Therefore, you should start a new question. (Output from `apt list` suggests that the package "skypeforlinux" is not installed, so it can't be removed.)