# Is there an easy way to fully remove WineHQ and then install it again? I'm not managing to do it. (Lubuntu 20.04)

Tags: command-line, package-management, lubuntu, wine

I installed the stable version of WineHQ using the winehq.org repositories.

I have been using wine for a while and in the meantime I have found several problems. Wine was running perfectly when I first installed but now it got problematic. These problems are too much of a pain for me to bother trying to fix, so I just want to fully remove wine and then install it again.

I have been trying to fully reinstall or fully reset wine in my system, but every time I try to do it wine gives me the same problems and behaves the same way as if it wasn't really fully reinstalled.

I have tried `sudo apt remove winehq-stable` and then install it again;
I also tried `sudo apt remove wine*` and then install again; and `sudo apt-get install winehq-stable --reinstall`. None of these worked for fully reinstalling/reseting wine in my system, so I'm here to ask what can I do to achieve that.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Unless you have a specific need for an advanced version of wine, remove everything you did before (including the ppa) and just install from the repos using `sudo apt install wine-stable`

Comment: You can remove wine but without purging configuration files and also "rm"-ing files you added yourself (even if it is by altering something using wine) your problems are going to return. The problem is likely not the installer on our end but the config inside wine. BTW: the "*" is not a wildcard and probably does not do what you believe it does: see https://askubuntu.com/a/957466/15811

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the advice about the asterisk. After reading the Q&A you mentioned, I believe the argument "wine*" I used was interpreted as a regular expression and as a consequence it probably removed packages that had nothing to do with wine. I will investigate the terminal's log file.