# Deleting Wine from my chromebook

Tags: wine, chromebook

I recently tried to install a game called league of legends on my chromebook by downloading wine. It looked like it was working but I think I ran out of sapce. I am now trying to delete it becasue it is affecting other applications. When I looked at other threads I tried following them, but nothing worked. Can someone help me?

when I type in:
sudo apt-get remove wine* --purge

and later it allows me to type [Y/N]

It says:
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
unable to flush /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i after padding: No space left on device
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)
E: Couldn't record the approved state changes as dpkg selection states

Comment: Do not use * in apt. It is not a wildcard (see for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why) .  And the answer is to make space. Start by deleting old logfiles in /var/log/

Comment: I took away the * but it gave me the same messgae.

Comment: How would I go about deleting old log files?

Comment: Right click on the file, press shift and you will see that 'remove to wastebin' (or something similar ) changes to remove ( permanantly ). Or selct the file and press 'shift'+ 'delete' on your keyboard. You need the space to remove/unistall the game or 'Wine'. Or you can move videos/music/photos to a usb stick to create space ( if your /home and / are installed on the same partition ).