# E: Unable to locate package php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf

Tags: apt, php

I tried to uninstall PHP but I got the following error instead. What does this error mean and how to solve it?

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge php*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf'
```

Comment: * is NOT a wildcard for apt. Why the need to remove it? It should not harm anything in your system :)

Comment: @Rinzwind It's not safe to rely on, yes ... But, if a simulation is run using `*`  ... e.g. `apt-get -s remove 'vlc*'` ... `apt` will state that it is using it as a globbing character an will print something like `Note, selecting 'vlc-plugin-qt' for glob 'vlc*'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the unquoted `php*` is expanded by your shell to a filename(`php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf`) that exists in your current working directory ... In which case, the expansion will happen before the package name/name pattern is passed to `apt-get` ... Therefore all `apt-get` will see in this case is `php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf` and not `php*` ... You can run `set -x`(*to enable printing command debugging/execution*) in your terminal then run your command to see that what is actually passed to `apt-get` looks like this:

```
apt-get remove --purge php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf
```

and not:

```
apt-get remove --purge php*
```

as you might think.

You can prevent that expansion by quoting it(i.e. either `"php*"` or `'php*'`) ... Note that single quotes `'...'` can be safer in this case as [noted by @Thomas Ward](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464281/how-to-delete-php#comment2564416_1464289).

Also, your assumption of `apt-get` using the globbing pattern to match any package starting with `php` in its name might not be always correct/safe ... `apt-get` seems to, sometimes, might handle that as a regular expression and not a globbing pattern ... As you see in your case `apt-get` tried both `by glob` and `by regex`:

```
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php-7-v-podlinnike.pdf'
```

So, you might want to use something like `'^php.*'` instead as a safer alternative.

I would, however, advice you to be **very cautious** when mass removing packages and carefully read the list of packages to be removed before answering yes to action/s suggested by `apt-get` ... See for example [apt-get remove with wildcard removed way more than expected. why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/210976).

Also, as a side note, if you exclude the `--purge` option, packages will still be removed but configuration files will be saved in case you decide to reinstall a certain package later so it will use those configuration files(*so it behaves the same way it used to before you remove it*) instead of starting from scratch.

You can also use the `-s` option to simulate the result of your `apt-get` command without actually removing any package like so:

```
apt-get -s remove 'php*'
```

Comment: I would use single quotes because `*` sometimes is mishandled in double-quotes (anything in bash single quotes is processed verbatim without expansion/replacement)

Comment: @ThomasWard It doesn't harm to single quote ... Bot isn't necessary either ... Only variables are expanded inside double quotes ... So unless `$` is used in the package name  which shouldn't be used ... It is passed by the shell to `apt-get` in single qoutes anyway(*which can be observed if `set -x` command debugging is used*) ... However, earlier expansion of parameters by the shell might/will happen ... You got a point there so I will edit the answer :-)