# Kubuntu? What is that..?

Tags: kubuntu

Okay so when I was running the Ubuntu installer I found something called "Desktop Interface". It was apparently selected as Ubuntu. I looked at the full set of options and found out that there's Kubuntu there! I want to know what Kubuntu is. If I can get it on Virtualbox then how? I want to try out Kubuntu but I don't want to over write my Ubuntu with Kubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu flavors or derivatives**

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors

> Introduction to Flavors
>
> The difference between the flavors are in the set of packages
>   installed. However, all flavors of Ubuntu use the same repository for
>   downloading updates, so the same set of packages is available
>   regardless of which flavor you have installed...

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

> Derivatives Ubuntu is a popular operating system and a popular
>   starting point for people who want to create their own operating
>   systems.
>
> Derivatives of Ubuntu include local-language and hardware-specific
>   versions...

**Kubuntu**

http://www.kubuntu.org/

> Kubuntu is based on free software from many
>   communities of developers including:
>
> - KDE Software, applications that
>     give you power
> - Plasma, KDE's desktop and netbook workspaces
> - Linux, an operating system kernel taking over the world   Debian, supplying
>     most of our packages
> - Ubuntu, turning free software into distributions such as Kubuntu

**KDE**

http://www.kde.org/

> The KDE® Community is an international technology team dedicated to
>   creating a free and user-friendly computing experience, offering an
>   advanced graphical desktop, a wide variety of applications for
>   communication, work, education and entertainment and a platform to
>   easily build new applications upon...

**Installing KDE or Kubuntu**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE

**Removing desktop enviroments**

[How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)

[How to remove desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147858/how-to-remove-desktop-environments)

Answer (score 0):

Install the KDE window manager. This will not reinstall or erase your current installation.

Use the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

More instructions:

- Make sure you click the options button in the lower corner when you get to the login prompt.
- When it asks for what session, choose KDE.

Answer (score 0):

In linux there are any number of different window managers (desktops if you like from windows, but there more than that in linux). The basic ubuntu install uses one desktop (based on gnome) but there are others like KDE (which kubuntu uses) and XFace and many others that determine how the information on the system is displayed, how much memory they use, how configurable they are etc. etc.

The one constant with Linux is that there are 100 ways to skin a cat, you should try several of them if your new and find the way to skin the cat you like.

Answer (score 0):

It's a desktop interface.  Ubuntu will install Unity desktop by default.  If you select Kubuntu, it will install KDE desktop instead of Unity desktop.