# How do I install and uninstall kubuntu desktop environment?

Tags: uninstall, software-installation, kde

I just want to try `kde`. How do I install it through the command line? If I don't like it, how do I uninstall it through the command line?

Comment: Also see [How to remove desktop environments?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147858/how-to-remove-desktop-environments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
To install **Kubuntu desktop** use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

To remove **Kubuntu desktop** use the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

*Note: You can replace **Kubuntu** for any other Desktop Environment.*

Comment: This does nothing if kubuntu was installed from USB, and not manually later...