# How to remove kubuntu-desktop completely?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde

I was using Ubuntu 15.10 and decided to try KDE. I installed `kubuntu-desktop`. I did not like it and now want to remove it completely.
But the problem is, running this command

```
$ sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kubuntu-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
After this operation, 41.0 kB disk space will be freed.
```

which means it still is not removing it completely.
How do I remove it completely.

Comment: Or [How do I install and uninstall kubuntu desktop environment?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474427/how-do-i-install-and-uninstall-kubuntu-desktop-environment)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this command will remove kubuntu-desktop completely. Even if it says 41 kb of data will be removed, a lot of it will actually be removed. But there is a problem: KDE will be removed, but other programs installed with it will not.

I suggest that you look for every program that came with kubuntu-desktop and remove them one by one. That is the most safe way (KDE programs usually have a 'K' in the beginning of their names).

A pro tip: whenever you want to test a Desktop Enviroment, do not install it as recommended in most guides. Google for  core/minimal version. The core or minimal versions come only with the desktop, no extra software, making it way simpler to remove afterwards. These versions take a lot less disk space, too. For example, you can install 'xubuntu-core', for XFCE, 'lubuntu-core', for LXDE, 'ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends' for Unity, etc., etc.

Comment: Please check your first para. I think "Even if it says 41 kb of data will be removed, a lot of it will actually be removed" is wrong. I think only `kubuntu-desktop`, which is a metapackage, will be removed. Pacakages installed by the metapackage won't be removed.