# Non-interactive area overlapping desktop on lubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, netbeans

I'm running Lubuntu on a virtualbox and after certain time, one part of my screen will just lost control and can't interact with anything behind that area.

Also, right clicking on that area will show the context menu in Open Box style while my default desktop is lubuntu.

How do I fix this?

**update**
I think it has something to do with Netbeans. Because it appears that everytime it happens, Netbeans is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution. The problem doesn't happen anymore (tested for 2 days so far).

I removed the openbox desktop environment

```
sudo apt-get purge openbox obconf obmenu
```

Also removed Cairo. I'm not sure which one solved the problem, but definitely not needing them anymore.

[How to remove desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147858/how-to-remove-desktop-environments)